# Pandas equivalent of Oracle Lead/Lag function

Tags: python, pandas

First I'm new to pandas, but I'm already falling in love with it.  I'm trying to implement the equivalent of the Lag function from Oracle.

Let's suppose you have this DataFrame:

```
Date                   Group      Data
2014-05-14 09:10:00        A         1
2014-05-14 09:20:00        A         2
2014-05-14 09:30:00        A         3
2014-05-14 09:40:00        A         4
2014-05-14 09:50:00        A         5
2014-05-14 10:00:00        B         1
2014-05-14 10:10:00        B         2
2014-05-14 10:20:00        B         3
2014-05-14 10:30:00        B         4
```

If this was an oracle database and I wanted to create a lag function grouped by the "Group" column and ordered by the Date I could easily use this function:

```
 LAG(Data,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Group ORDER BY Date ASC) AS Data_lagged
```

This would result in the following Table:

```
Date                   Group     Data    Data lagged
2014-05-14 09:10:00        A        1           Null
2014-05-14 09:20:00        A        2            1
2014-05-14 09:30:00        A        3            2
2014-05-14 09:40:00        A        4            3
2014-05-14 09:50:00        A        5            4
2014-05-14 10:00:00        B        1           Null
2014-05-14 10:10:00        B        2            1
2014-05-14 10:20:00        B        3            2
2014-05-14 10:30:00        B        4            3
```

In pandas I can set the date to be an index and use the shift method:

```
db["Data_lagged"] = db.Data.shift(1)
```

The only issue is that this doesn't group by a column.  Even if I set the two columns Date and Group as indexes, I would still get the "5" in the lagged column.

Is there a way to implement the equivalent of the Lead and lag functions in Pandas?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You could perform a [groupby/apply (shift) operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine):

```
In [15]: df['Data_lagged'] = df.groupby(['Group'])['Data'].shift(1)

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
                Date Group  Data  Data_lagged
2014-05-14  09:10:00     A     1          NaN
2014-05-14  09:20:00     A     2            1
2014-05-14  09:30:00     A     3            2
2014-05-14  09:40:00     A     4            3
2014-05-14  09:50:00     A     5            4
2014-05-14  10:00:00     B     1          NaN
2014-05-14  10:10:00     B     2            1
2014-05-14  10:20:00     B     3            2
2014-05-14  10:30:00     B     4            3

[9 rows x 4 columns]
```

To obtain the `ORDER BY Date ASC` effect, you must sort the DataFrame first:

```
df['Data_lagged'] = (df.sort_values(by=['Date'], ascending=True)
                       .groupby(['Group'])['Data'].shift(1))
```

Answer (score 17):

For lead operation in pandas, one need to just use `shift(-1)` instead of 1

`df['Data_lead'] = df.groupby(['Group'])['Data'].shift(-1)`

Comment: repeat of the accepted answer from 4 years prior

Comment: My bad - you said *-1* instead of *1*.  Unfortunately i can not reverse the downvote since it's locked. If you make any changes to the answer I can reverse my vote

Comment: I have edited, please update it @WestCoastProjects