# Groupby and lag all columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to lag every column in a dataframe, by group. I have a frame like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('2015-11-20', periods=6, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time=index, grp=['A']*3 + ['B']*3, col1=[1,2,3]*2,
    col2=['a','b','c']*2)).set_index(['time','grp'])
```

which looks like

```
                col1 col2
time       grp           
2015-11-20 A       1    a
2015-11-21 A       2    b
2015-11-22 A       3    c
2015-11-23 B       1    a
2015-11-24 B       2    b
2015-11-25 B       3    c
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
                col1 col2 col1_lag col2_lag
time       grp                     
2015-11-20 A       1    a        2        b
2015-11-21 A       2    b        3        c
2015-11-22 A       3    c       NA       NA
2015-11-23 B       1    a        2        b
2015-11-24 B       2    b        3        c
2015-11-25 B       3    c       NA       NA
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664877/pandas-equivalent-of-oracle-lead-lag-function) manages the result for a single column, but I have an arbitrary number of columns, and I want to lag all of them. I can use `groupby` and `apply`, but `apply` runs the `shift` function over each column independently, and it doesn't seem to like receiving an `[nrow, 2]` shaped dataframe in return. Is there perhaps a function like `apply` that acts on the whole group sub-frame? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

IIUC, you can simply use `level="grp"` and then shift by -1:

```
>>> shifted = df.groupby(level="grp").shift(-1)
>>> df.join(shifted.rename(columns=lambda x: x+"_lag"))
                col1 col2  col1_lag col2_lag
time       grp                              
2015-11-20 A       1    a         2        b
2015-11-21 A       2    b         3        c
2015-11-22 A       3    c       NaN      NaN
2015-11-23 B       1    a         2        b
2015-11-24 B       2    b         3        c
2015-11-25 B       3    c       NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I can't remember why I thought I needed to do it with  `apply` - maybe it'll come to me later.

Comment: Hrm.. I just realised that the reason I was trying it a different way is because the format `.shift(periods=1, freq='1D')` doesn't work with `.groupby`  - I actually already [reported this as a bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11452) - must have been having a bad week last week. It's since been changed in pandas so that it gives a not-implemented error. Hrm.

Comment: Any thoughts on how one could take this exact same approach but grouping by two columns instead of just the one?

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient reputation to reply to [Ricky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5855996/ricky)'s question in a comment, but you can simply add additional fields to groupby in a list, like so:

```
>>> shifted = df.groupby(["first_col", "second_col"]).shift(-1)
```

and then proceed with any subsequent steps as normal. Keep in mind the resulting df will be a grouped object with levels, so if you want to remove these afterwards you will need to call

```
>>> df_new = df_grouped.reset_index()
```

at the end. Hope this helps.