# level name b is not the name of the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to use a groupby on a dataframe as described here: [Groupby and lag all columns of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907537/groupby-and-lag-all-columns-of-a-dataframe)

For that I created this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data=range(1,101)
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.columns=["a"]
df["b"]=np.round( df["a"] / 5)
print(df)
shifted = df.groupby(level="b").shift(-1)
df=df.join(shifted)
print(df)
```

Unfortunatly this throws a "ValueError: level name b is not the name of the index" error and I cannot seem to figure out why. Printing the df shows that it has only a single level of indexes with "b" being in it.

Anyone know how to get this to work?

PS: I am trying to get a shift on certain columns but on group level.

Comment: level in `groupby` refers to the level in the multindex of the dataframe. You don't have a multindex so you shouldn't use that parameter. Try to use: `groupby(by="b"))`

Comment: Thank you! this works, I cant point to this as the solution so I can only upvote

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!