# How to fill the cell (i,j) with the cell (i-1,j-1) in a DataFram in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, cell

At first, I wanna apologize for my wording since I was not sure how to ask my question. Suppose that I have a dataframe as follows

**'T'  'Y'    'item'  'item_p'**

A  |    2001   |   2   |  Nan

A  |    2002   |   3  |   Nan

A  |    2003   |  5  |   Nan

A  |   2004    |  6    | Nan

A  |   2005    | 7    | Nan

B  |    2001   |  9  |   Nan

B  |    2002   |   3   |  Nan

B  |   2003   |   5   |  Nan

B  |    2004   |   6 |    Nan

B  |   2005    |  7 |    Nan

I want each cell in the column 'item_p' be filled with the value of the previous value of the column 'item'

So the result must be as bellow:

**'T'  'Y'    'item'  'item_p'**

A    |  2001 |     2   |  Nan

A     | 2002  |    3    | 2

A    |  2003   |   5   |  3

A   |   2004    |  6  |   5

A  |    2005     | 7   |  6

B |     2001 |     9  |   7

B     | 2002  |    3 |    9

B    |  2003   |   5    | 3

B   |   2004    |  6   |  5

B  |    2005  |    7  |   6

I have done the task with a nested for loops but I think there is some better way to do it. Is there any command to do such a task

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664877/pandas-equivalent-of-oracle-lead-lag-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas equivalent of Oracle Lead/Lag function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664877/pandas-equivalent-of-oracle-lead-lag-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use df.shift()

In your example:

```
df['item_p'] = df['item'].shift(1)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: @user2356563 Don't forget to mark the answer as your chosen answer

Comment: I am new here, How should I do it?