# Iterating / Slicing over a dataframe and performing mathematical calculations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi8XC.jpg)

the operation that I intend to perform is whenever there is a '2' in the column 3, we need to take that entry and take the column 1 value of that entry and subtract the column 1 value of the previous entry and then multiply the result by a constant integer (say 5). 
 For example: From the image we have a '2' in column 3 at 6:00 and the value of column 1 for that entry is 0.011333 and take the previous column 1 entry which is 0.008583 and perform the following.
(0.011333 - 0.008583)* 5. 
This I want to perform everytime when we receive a '2' in column 3 in a dataframe. Please help. I am not able to get the write code to perform the above operation.

Comment: Please provide code to replicate data, not just the image of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps: 
You can use df.shift(1) to get the previous row and np.where to get the row satisfying your condition

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['ABC', 1, 0, 0],
                   ['DEF', 2, 0, 0],
                   ['GHI', 3, 0, 0],
                   ['JKL', 4, 0, 2],
                   ['MNO', 5, 0, 2],
                   ['PQR', 6, 0, 2],
                   ['STU', 7, 0, 0]],
                  columns=['Date & Time', 'column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3'])

df['new'] = np.where(df['column 3'] == 2, df['column 1'] - df['column 1'].shift(1) * 5, 0)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Date & Time  column 1  column 2  column 3   new
0         ABC         1         0         0   0.0
1         DEF         2         0         0   0.0
2         GHI         3         0         0   0.0
3         JKL         4         0         2 -11.0
4         MNO         5         0         2 -15.0
5         PQR         6         0         2 -19.0
6         STU         7         0         0   0.0
```

You can change your calculations as you want. In the  `else` part you can put `np.NaN` or any other calculation if you want.

Comment: This logic works perfectly fine in my context. I wasn't aware of numpy's shift function. Thankyou so much for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Done. . I'm new to  stackoverflow and so am not quite aware of the reward system. Thankyou, once again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Would something like that do the job ?

```
dataframe = [
    [1,3,6,6,7],
    [4,3,5,6,7],
    [12,3,2,6,7],
    [2,3,7,6,7],
    [9,3,5,6,7],
    [13,3,2,6,7]
]
constant = 5
list_of_outputs = []

for row in dataframe:
    if row[2] == 2:
        try:
            output = (row[0] - prev_entry) * constant
            list_of_outputs.append(output)
        except:
            print("No previous entry!")
    prev_entry = row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664877/pandas-equivalent-of-oracle-lead-lag-function) will help you

I think in SQL way, so basically you will make new column that filled with the value from the row above it.

```
df['column1_lagged'] = df['column 1'].shift(1)
```

Then you create another column that do the calculation

```
constant = 5
df['calculation'] = (df['column 1'] - df['column1_lagged'])*constant
```

After that you just slice the dataframe to your condition (column 3 with '2's)

```
condition = df['column 3'] == 2
df[condition]
```

Comment: Yes, I have applied the same logic in a single line of code as davidbilla mentioned. This logic works perfectly fine for me. Thankyou for your help, really appreciate it.